# How do I find the equation of parabola with vertex (0, 0) and focus (1, 1)?

Tags: geometry

I know, there is a formula $(y−k)^2=4p(x−h)$. But, in this case, points aren't on the  same axis, so what should I do?

Comment: You can use the [Equation of the parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case).

Comment: Note: You will have to find the equation of the directrix using the focus and the vertex. The directrix is perpendicular to the line through the vertex and focus, and the vertex is equidistant from the focus and the directrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary remark : The formula you give for a parabola with vertex in $(h,k)$ and **horizontal axis** is

$$(y−k)^2=2p(x−h)$$

(coefficient $2$ instead of $4$) where parameter $p$ is the distance from focus to directrix. But here, as you have remarked it, the axis isn't horizontal.

Let $V(0,0)$ be the vertex and $F(1,1)$ be the focus.
As the directrix (D) is orthogonal to line $VF$, it is not difficult to see that the equation of (D) is $x+y=-2$. Then we express that this parabola is the locus of points at equal distance from (D) and from $F$.

$$\dfrac{|x+y+2|}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}\tag{1}$$

(on the LHS one finds the classical formula for the distance of 
a point to a straight line : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

Squaring LHS and RHS in (1) gives :

$$\dfrac12(x^2+y^2+4+4x+4y+2xy)=x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1$$

finally giving :

> $$ x^2 + y^2 - 2xy - 8x  - 8y \ = \ 0.$$

[image]

Comment: Just fixed a sign error.

Comment: Nice answer. Really helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @steven gregory Thank you very much for having provided this nice graphical representation.

Answer (score 0):

It just requires a slight modification to your equation. Observe that in your equation, $y-k=0$ is the parabola’s axis and $x-h=0$ is the tangent at its vertex, to try generalizing this equation by using equations for lines that aren’t parallel to the coordinate axes: Start from $$(ax+by+c)^2=4p(bx-ay+d),$$ where $ax+by+c=0$ is an equation of the parabola’s axis and $bx-ay+d=0$ is an equation of the tangent at its vertex, i.e., the perpendicular to the axis through the vertex. In order for $p$ to be equal to the focus-vertex distance you will also need to have $a^2+b^2=1$.

For your parabola, the requisite equation of the axis is easily found to be $${x\over\sqrt2}-{y\over\sqrt2}=0$$ and the equation of the perpendicular through the vertex is $${x\over\sqrt2}+{y\over\sqrt2}=0.$$ An equation for this parabola is therefore $$\left({x\over\sqrt2}-{y\over\sqrt2}\right)^2 = 4\sqrt2\left({x\over\sqrt2}+{y\over\sqrt2}\right).$$